# Type definition of RangePicker onChange date paramater

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, ant-design-pro

As per documentation ant design 4.7

```
onChange    Callback function, can be executed when the selected time is changing   function(dates: [moment, moment], dateStrings: [string, string])
```

Error

```
Type '(date: Array<Moment>, dateString: Array<string>) => void' is not assignable to type '(values: RangeValue<Moment>, formatString: [string, string]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'date' and 'values' are incompatible.
    Type 'RangeValue<Moment>' is not assignable to type 'Moment[]'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Moment[]'.
```

Code

```
  const dateTimeOnChange = (
    date: Array<Moment>,
    dateString: Array<string>
  ): void => {
    console.log(date);
    console.log(dateString);
  };
```

Can't find type definition for and design RangePicker onChange 1st parameter type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message and the docs the problem is pretty clear. The parameters are not arbitrary length arrays, but rather fixed size arrays (aka tuples), also the `date` parameter may be `null`

Try

```
const dateTimeOnChange = (
    date: [Moment, Moment] | null,
    dateString: [string, string]
  ): void => {
    console.log(date);
    console.log(dateString);
  };
```

You could probably also use `date: RangeValue<Moment>` if `RangeValue` is exported from the module it is declared in.

Comment: Yes RangeValue can be imported is this okay if it is imported this deep.                         
import { RangeValue } from '../../../../node_modules/rc-picker/lib/interface';

Comment: @Chris hm ..it's not great .. see if maybe there is another suggestion, sometimes there may be more than one, and the first is not necessarily the best. It's a type.. so this import will not make it into your runtime code .. still rather ugly but id still use it as it is the actual required type. Maybe `rc-picker/lib/interface` also works ?

Comment: Yeah it works! the reason I imported that way because I don't get any intellisense, thinking that it may not work but it's okay now. thank you for your time.

Comment: @Chris did you find a better alternative or a way to  properly do this istead of going all the way and importing it from node_modules?

Comment: @tHeSiD  rc-picker/lib/interface